# What's the correct type of brackets to use in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

I had my first day of Linear Algebra today, and we got introduced to matrices, one thing that kept nagging me though, was that I kept seeing matrices written in a few different styles, namely

$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array} \right] $$

as well as

$$ B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array} \right) $$

and on really rare occasions I've even seen

$$ C = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array} \right\} $$

So my question is, which of these is considered most correct to use? $A$, $B$, or $C$?

Comment: Why does it matter? Most modern texts use the second, but it really has no consequence.

Comment: The first two styles are ubiquitous and which one you use is a matter of taste. It's unlikely that anyone will fail to understand what you mean either way. On the other hand, I've never seen the third style used. I would not suggest using it if your goal is to use a standard notation.

Comment: IMHO, on this site, use the $2^{nd}$ style as default unless you have equations the have many matrix multiplication on a single line. In that case, switch to use the $1^{st}$ style because it consume less space. Whatever you choose, make sure it is consistent within a question/answer.

Comment: As an aside, the first style can be achieved with `\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{bmatrix}` as $$ \begin{bmatrix} a& b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$, the second with `\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{pmatrix}`. The `b` stands for "brackets" and `p` for "parentheses". Both are common enough that the American Mathematical Society created the above LaTeX short-cuts for typesetting them (instead of `\left[ \begin{array} ...`).

Comment: @WillieWong what package are those in? it would save me a lot of time...

Comment: In LaTeX, those are defined as part of the `amsmath` collection. As you can see in my comment above, those are included by default in the MathJax configuration that is run on this website to process mathematics.

Comment: Our proffesor uses ||A|| instead of brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all used, mostly interchangeably, depending on the style of the author.

Comment: so basically there's no real difference at all..?

Comment: A comment as an answer......

Comment: @Vladhagen A waste of time as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer $A$. Some author $B$. I've never seen $C$.